# How to create a JavaConfig factory method for a Spring Data repository with constructor injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a simple application with repositories, services and controllers. I have my configuration in a configuration class where I bind my interfaces to implementations. All dependencies(except the `EntityManager`) are injected using constructor injection.

My problem is how I should inject the `CrudRepository` instance into my services, since I do not have any implementations of the `CrudRepository`.

My services look kind of like this:

```
@Service
public class ConcreteXService implements XService {

    private final XRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ConcreteXService(XRepository repository){
        this.repository=repository;
    }

    // …
}
```

My config looks kind of like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("some.package")
public class MyConf{

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        // …
    }

    @Bean
    public XController xController(){
        return new ConcreteXController(xService());
    }

    @Bean XService xService(){
        return new ConcreteXService(/*would like to write xRepository() here but that method does not exist.*/);
    }
    //Lots of other beans are omitted
}
```

My `CrudRepository` instances are defined as interfaces that extend `CrudRepository<…>` and they seem to work if I just field inject them in a test, but I do not know how to write a config that can constructor inject them, since there is no implementation. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to not to manually declare beans for application components but simply use component scanning and autowiring. So basically get rid of the `@Bean` methods for service and controller and rather use `@ComponentScan` with your applications base package.

If you really need to use JavaConfig for those, you can either make the dependency an argument of the factory method:

```
 @Bean XService service(XRepository repository){
   return new ConcreteXService(repository);
 }
```

Alternatively, autowire the repository into the configuration class:

```
 @Autowired XRepository repository;

 @Bean XService xService(){
    return new ConcreteXService(repository);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I personally prefer the second option.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to calling `xRepository()` method, you can specify your repository interface as a method parameter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("some.package")
public class MyConf{

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        //omitted
    }

    @Bean
    public XController xController(xService xService){
        return new ConcreteXController(xService);
    }

    @Bean XService xService(xRepository xRepository){
        return new ConcreteXService(xRepository);
    }
    //Lots of other beans are omitted
}
```